# How to search all the photos on my site for possible copyright violations

Tags: media-library

I'd like to search hundreds of photos in a wordpress media library on my organization's site to make sure there are none that are violating a copyright.

How can I efficiently search all the photos to see if they have copyrights on other sites? I'm guessing I'd do a reverse image search on every photo. We use Wordpress and have an image library, so I'm wondering if there's a way to quickly search the entire library.

I've googled how to search a site for image copyright violations and the answers I've seen so far have been about reverse image searching a set of photos, which is for protecting copyrighted images against unauthorized use on other sites. I want to do something different, though. I want to search every image on my site to find any that might be violating copyrights.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.